# find the absolute file path of a data set in R studio for rattle

Tags: r, file, path, rattle

I am working on  R Win7 x64.

I have installed and opened a data mining tool rattle. http://rattle.togaware.com/

After loading the library in R studio, I can access the data set contained in the library.

```
 library(rattle)

 Data sets in package ‘rattle’:

 audit                     Sample dataset for illustration Rattle
                           functionality.
 locationsAUS              Sample and full dataset for illustrating Rattle
                            functionality.
 weather                   Sample and full dataset for illustrating Rattle
                            functionality.
 weatherAUS                Sample and full dataset for illustrating Rattle
                            functionality.
 wine                      The wine dataset from the UCI Machien Learning
                             Repository.

 rattle()  // open a GUI
```

But, in the GUI I cannot see the weather.csv file which can be accessed in R studio.

Why ?

How to find the absolute file path of weather.csv in R studio ?

I need to copy it to the dir that can be accessed by rattle GUI.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no `weather.csv`. `weather` is a dataset that already exists in the `rattle` package. It is not `csv`.

Comment: `list.files(paste0(Sys.getenv()["R_LIBS_USER"], "/", "rattle/csv"))`

Comment: @Ramnath The `rattle` package has CSV copies of all its datasets too, presumably so people can practise reading them in.

Answer (score 2):

You can see all the files in the `rattle` package using

```
dir(system.file(package = "rattle"), recursive = TRUE)
```

The path to the one you want is retrieved with

```
system.file("csv", "weather.csv", package = "rattle")
```

This works whether you use RStudio or any other IDE for R.